# Proof that unit complex numbers 1, z and w form an equilateral triangle

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, triangles

Let $w$ and $z$ be unit complex numbers such that $Arg(z) = \theta$.
Knowing that $1+z+w=0$, show that the geometrical images of $1,z$ and $w$ form an equilateral triangle.

This should be easy but I do not find a solution within your previous questions. I tried to measure the distance between the vertices.

Knowing that they are all unit complex numbers, we have $|z| = |w| = |1| = 1$. Knowing that $Arg(z) = \theta$, we can say immediately that $z= e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$.

We also know that

$1+z+w=0 <=>  w=-1-z$

Therefore, we have

$ |z-w| = |z-(-1-z)| = |z+1+z| = |2z+1| = |2(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta) + 1| = |(2 \cos \theta  + 1) + i (2\sin \theta) | = \sqrt{(2 \cos \theta +1)^2 + 4 \sin^2 \theta} = \sqrt{4 \cos^2 \theta + 4 \cos \theta + 1 + 4 \sin^2 \theta  } = \sqrt{4 (\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta) +4 \cos \theta + 1} = \sqrt{4 + 1 + 4 \cos \theta} = \sqrt{5+4 \cos \theta} $

$ |w-1| = |-1-z-1| = |-2-z| = |-2 - \cos \theta - i \sin \theta| = \sqrt{(-2- \cos \theta)^2 + (-\sin \theta)^2} = \sqrt{4 + 4 \cos \theta + \cos^2 \theta + sin^2 \theta} = \sqrt{4 + 4 \cos \theta + 1} = \sqrt{5 + 4 \cos \theta}$

So far so good, I have two equal sides. We have $|z-1|$ left though,

$ |z-1| = |\cos \theta + i \sin \theta - 1| = | \cos \theta - 1 + i \sin \theta| = \sqrt{(cos \theta - 1)^2 + \sin^2 \theta} = \sqrt{\cos^2 \theta - 2 \cos \theta + 1 + \sin^2 \theta} = \sqrt{\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta + 1 - 2 \cos \theta} = \sqrt{1 + 1 - 2 \cos \theta} = \sqrt{2 - 2 \cos \theta} $

Therefore, this side appears to have different length than the other two, which makes of this an isosceles triangle, not equilateral. Why is this rationale wrong and how could I prove this using only these data?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy computation shows that $1=|w|^2=|1+z|^2=2 +2 \cos \theta$, hence $\cos \theta=-1/2$. It follows that $5+ 4 \cos \theta=2-2 \cos \theta$ and everything is fine !

Answer (score 2):

The geometrical images of $\, 1, z, w \,$ form a triangle. We are given that
$\, |1| = |z| = |w|,\,$ thus the unit circle is the circumcircle of this triangle and $0$ is the circumcenter. We are given that $\, 1 + z + w = 0,\,$
thus the centroid is also $0$. From the Wikipedia article
[Euler line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_line)

> [...] the orthocenter, circumcenter and centroid are collinear. [...] In equilateral triangles, these four points coincide, but in any other triangle they are all distinct from each other.

The circumcenter and centroid coincide, thus the triangle is equilateral.

Answer (score 1):

It is sufficient but a bit tedious to explicitly calculate the real and imaginary parts.

Write $w=a+bi$ and $z=c+di$.

Then from $1+w+z=0$ we have $a+c=-1$ and $b+d=0$ so $b=-d$.

As these are unit complex numbers $a^2+b^2=1=c^2+d^2$

Since $b=-d$ we have $a^2+(-d)^2=c^2+d^2$ hence $a^2=c^2$ so $a=\pm c$.

As $a+c=-1$, $a=-c$ is impossible. Thus $a=c=-1/2$.

Since $a^2+b^2=1$ substituting $a=-1/2$ gives $b^2 = 3/4$ so $b=\pm \sqrt{3}/2$.

The points $1, -1/2 + \sqrt{3}/2i, -1/2 -\sqrt{3}/2i$ are exactly those on the equilateral triangle, which you can prove by calculating the distances between them or evaluating $e^{\pm 2\pi/3}$.

We see the solution using pure complex numbers (Fred's) is much cleaner.